# How to convert Post Object Custom Field into Tags

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-field, tags

so I've used this script in from this post to automatically convert an existing custom field into a tag. **The problem is that my custom field is a Post Object. SO, it is creating a tag with the post ID. Can you advise on how to tag as the actual post title?**

[How to convert custom field value to tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239881/how-to-convert-custom-field-value-to-tag)

```
function my_migration_script() {
  global $wpdb;

  // Quick and dirty way to get post ids. Normally don't use this method.
  $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post'" );

  // Loop through all ids.
  foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {

    // Grab the location meta value if it exists.
    if ( $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'location', true ) ) {

      // Remove any commas since it's used as a delimiter.
      $value = str_replace ( ',', '', $value );

      // Create a tag based on the `location` custom field value.
      wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $value );
    }
  }

  // Uncomment if you'd rather delete without verifying first.
  // $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'meta_key' => 'location' ) );
}

// Kick off the script.
my_migration_script();
```

**Updated w/ var_dump values:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10362" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13239" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" [1]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" [1]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" [1]=> string(5) "13236" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" [1]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10346" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" [1]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14060" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" [1]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" [1]=> string(5) "13236" } string(5) "13234" array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14060" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14060" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" [1]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10366" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13452" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14798" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14680" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13234" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "87" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13610" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13236" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "14680" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10345" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "13889"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `$value` actually returns a post's ID. Replace the code

```
wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $value );
```

With

```
wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, sanitize_title( get_the_title( $value[0] ) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It makes sense, but for some reason, it did not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of your `$value` when you var_dump?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. But, when I executed the script the first time, it was returning the Post ID properly. I referenced a few tags and they seemed to be tagged with the correct Post ID.

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $value )` before your `wp_add_post_tags` code. If you are sure the `$value` will return a post ID, the above code should actually work.

Comment: OK, I'll try that now. Where do I see the output of the var_dump? Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: Normally in the same window unless there is an automatic redirection somewhere.  Or you do a `die` or `exit` after your function call to stop any other script to run to view this.

Comment: OK, edited original post to show var_dump values

Comment: if this is `var_dump( $value )` use the code below `wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, sanitize_title( get_the_title( $value[0] )`

Comment: boom....thank you!!!! That worked!